# RGB Heatmap to 1D heatmap

Tags: image-processing, heatmap, opencv, python

From an external function I get a RGB 3 channel heatmap. I guess to visulize it nicely. Unfortunately a headmap in that form is not ideal for processing. I can't change the heatmap generation as it is an external functionality. Now I would like to convert it so the RGB heatmap only ranges between 0 and 255. Is there a good algorithm for this.
I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

My approch at the moment:

```
c = (a[...,2]/255)*85+(a[...,1]/255)*170+(a[...,0]/255)*255
c = np.interp(c, (c.min(), c.max()), (0, 255))
```

I look at the channels individually and calculate a weighted sum.
But this is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the colormap palette used? Something you can find on https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

What I'd do is construct a 3D→1D lookup table. Use the RGB values as indices into a 3D array of scalar values. Of course for best results you should know what colormap was used in the first place.

Since LUTs can grow big rather fast, and also fetching memory to perform the lookup isn't the most efficient thing in the world, the next step would be fitting some modelling function (splines, polynomials, something like that) to the LUT to get a close approximation that's quicker to evaluate.